# questions about gas fireplace pilot light

Tags: gas, fireplace, gas-burner

I'm troubleshooting a gas (propane) fireplace.   The pilot won't stay lit (after I ignite it with piezo start and let it burn 30-60 secs.   I pulled the unit out to have a better look, and then decided to try again to light the pilot - this time it worked.

Here is a picture of the pilot assembly, from the manual ...

[image]

... and here is a photo of a replacement pilot assembly (the exact correct part #) ...

[image]

Why does this thing have a thermopile AND a thermocouple ?  I thought they did the same thing: detect a lit pilot flame and allow a valve to continue providing gas to the pilot.  The "thermopile" seems to connect with two wires, as I expect, as it provides a signal of some millivolts to enable gas flow.   The "thermocouple" seems to connect with a small gas line of some kind.  What's the deal here ?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. If you find that difficult it may be because you're asking too much in one post.

Comment: Q2 would likely get closed if on its own as an opinion based question.

Comment: Ok, edited it to just the first question.   Not sure why though ... why clutter up the site with 3 questions, when they are closely-related, and a person who knows the answer to one probably knows the answer to all three.

Comment: Are you sure one of your sensors isn't a CO (carbon monoxide) sensor?  I think all recent gas fireplaces & log sets are required to have one.  It's to shut down the fireplace if the CO level gets too high.

Comment: Pretty sure.   They are labeled thermopile and thermocouple in that drawing.   BTW, the house has two CO detectors, as well as a plethora of smoke detectors.